# how to restart coldfusion using cronjob

Tags: 18.04, server, cron

I restart my ColdFusion service by this location  /opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/ than I execute ./coldfusion restart

so I want to set in a cronjob so what is a correct way to set it

Is this the correct way

```
0 6 * * * /opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/./coldfusion restart
```

or I am doing something wrong

I am using ubuntu 18.04 lts

Comment: Your cron job does not match the location that you specified in the first line (there is a `2018` that you left out). Other than that, there is a `/.` in the path that doesn't do anything. So the command should be `/opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion restart`. Other than that, this looks fine to me.

Comment: @Jos we restart it using ./coldfusion restart command , are you sure we can remove ./ from cronjob

Comment: Yes. The `./` in `./coldfusion` says "find the executable in the current working directory". That is not necessary if you provide full path to the executable, as you do in my `cron` command (and as you should in every `cron` command).

Comment: okay thanks @Jos

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work, but it is slightly more complex than needed. The `./` just means "the current directory". So when you first `cd /opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/` and then run `./coldfusion` that is exactly the same thing as *not* cd-ing to the directory and just running the executable using the full path: `/opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion`.

Now, what you added to your crontab was `/opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/./coldfusion restart` and this is 100% equivalent to `/opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion restart` because `./` means the current directory.

So you could just add this and it should work as expected:

```
0 6 * * * /opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion restart
```